# Can't rotate mesh in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I can rotate a mesh in three.js if I type in the incremental value, but if I use a variable that I didn't set in the animate function, then it doesn't work. Any variable that requires does a math operation before being enter causes the rotation to become NaN. I'm trying to use the mouse position as the variable for rotation and it works for changing the position of the object, but not rotation.

```js
function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame( animate ); 
    var inX = (mouseInX - (document.body.clientWidth / 2)) / 5000;
    var inY = (mouseInY - (document.body.clientHeight / 2)) / 5000;
    camera.position.x = inX;
    camera.position.y = -inY;
    
    //console.log(inX);
    
    
    mesh.rotateOnAxis(new THREE.Vector3 (0.0, 1.0, 0.0), inX); //This causes the mesh to vanish. If I log the roatation on the y axis it say NaN.
    mesh.rotateOnAxis(new THREE.Vector3 (0.0, 0.0, 1.0), 0.001); // This works if both of them have a number typed in like so.
    
    console.log(mesh.rotation.y + ", " + mesh.position.x);
 renderer.render( scene, camera );  
    lastMouseX = mouseInX;
}

function getCurrentMousePos(evt) {
    mouseInX = Number(evt.clientX);
    mouseInY = Number(evt.clientY);
}
```

Comment: Did you try `/ 5000.0` ?

Comment: Where are you declaring `mouseInX`? It's difficult to help you troubleshoot without more information.

Comment: I think you need to convert `inX` to radians.

Comment: Frederik.L, I tried using 5000.0 and it had no effect. Thanks for the advice regardless. Mahmudur Rahman, I don't see why I would have to convert to radians. The value is just an increment and I don't see why it would matter to rotating the mesh. Thanks anyway. DTC, I am calling the getCurrentMousePosition() function in the body of my web page. I call it on the onmousemove="" tag. Also, I set the evt variable to event. All it does is return the mouse's position in pixels across the body and stores them in the mouseInX and mouseInY variable